# Why doesn't the T-1000 retain the shape of the slain security guard?

Tags: the-terminator-series, terminator-2-judgment-day

In *Terminator 2: Judgment Day*, Inside Pescadero State Hospital, the T-1000 takes the "lucky day" security officer's shape just prior to slaying him. It then walks through the halls for a short time before reverting back to the default T-1000 shape. Why is this? Though the T-800 would have recognized the copy as the T-1000 in disguise, Sara and John would not have. And the T-1000, of course, had no way of knowing if John and Sara would be with the T-800 when it found them.

Comment: It seems that you of all users should be best qualified to answer :)

Comment: @yrodro Are you the legal guardian of John Connor? Could I speak to him, please?

Comment: Of course the directorial reason is to give Robert Patrick the screen time/presence that the role deserves...

Comment: That goes without saying. But obviously I was looking for a canon reason.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The official [Frakes novelisation](http://terminator.wikia.com/wiki/Terminator_2:_Judgment_Day_(Frakes_novel)) covers the T-1000's thought process. Officer Austin was chosen not only because of his status as a policeman but also because his physical profile was close to the T-1000's base form. Maintaining a different form requires additional energy that it doesn't want to waste:

> The T-1000 walked forward. **Because of the man’s obesity, it had been
>   stressing its ability to expand molecularly by remaining in the Lewis
>   form, so it had defaulted back to the more energy-efficient Officer
>   Austin.** It reached the bars. But it did not stop.
>
> Its body began to divide like Jell-O around the metal bars. As it
>   squeezed itself through like PlayDoh, its surface reformed perfectly.

Comment: I take it that "official" means "canon."

Comment: @T-1000 - The novels are 'based on' the screenplay and written in consultation with James Cameron. I always treat novelisations as fully canon ***unless otherwise contradicted by the original work***

Comment: And the comics are also canon?

Comment: @T-1000 - Yes. They're licensed properties but the general concensus is that they're only canon where not contradicted. If something happened in the film/TV series that doesn't happen in the comics, it's assumed that the comic is in error.

Comment: One of my favorite 'books' that I think both of you would love (and assume you own already): http://www.amazon.com/Terminator-Judgment-Illustrated-Screenplay-Applause/dp/1557830975 @T-1000

Comment: ***"Its body began to divide like Jell-O around the metal bars. As it squeezed itself through like PlayDoh, its surface reformed perfectly"*** That is pure literary brilliance.

Comment: @LegoStormtroopr - "*No one was moving, except one of the bikers. Robert Pantelli ate bad times for breakfast and spat out trouble for lunch. Most things in life didn’t surprise him. What he was looking at now did. He stopped puffing on his foul-smelling cigar and slowly lowered it, a dark smile spreading across his wet lips.*"

Comment: @Richard I need that book so damn much it hurts.